# How to chain RxJS5 operators into a new operator?

Tags: javascript, reactive-programming, rxjs, rxjs5

According to the [operator creation guide](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJS/blob/master/doc/operator-creation.md), i tried to chain some operators i used to an another operator but without any success.

```
function mySimpleOperator(actionName, iterable$, functionThatReturnAnObservable) {
   return Observable.create(subscriber => {
     var source = this;
     var subscription = source
       .interval(500)
       .skipUntil(iterable$.filter(({ action }) => action.type === actionName))
       .take(1)
       .flatMap(functionThatReturnAnObservable)
       .subscribe(value => {
         try {
           subscriber.next(value);
         } catch(err) {
           subscriber.error(err);
         }
     }, 
     err => subscriber.error(err),
     () => subscriber.complete());

     return subscription;
   });
}

Observable.prototype.mySimpleOperator = mySimpleOperator;
```

This function simply start an interval and will be skip until the actionName will be emitted.

But when i tried to use my operator

```
Observable.mySimpleOperator('APP_READY', source$, () => Observable.of({ type: 'DONE' })
```

It throw an error

```
Observable.mySimpleOperator is not a function
```

But if i do the intervall call outside my new operator it works ?!

```
Observable.interval(500).mySimpleOperatorWithoutIntervall('APP_READY', source$, () => Observable.of({ type: 'DONE' })
```

Any solutions ? :)

Answer (score 1):

You haven't added the operator to the object you added it to the `Observable.prototype` object. Which means it will only ever show up on existing `Observables` as an instance method. You need to add it to the Observable as `Observable.mySimpleOperator`.

Internally you need to change `source.interval(500)` to `Observable.interval(500)` which is the static method.